# Updating property of nested object in Redux using action

Tags: reactjs, redux

Inside my reducer, my initial state has a structure like the following:

```
const initialState = {
    showOverlay: false,
    chosenAnimal: null,
    sliderValue: 0,
    colorValues: {
        a: null,
        c: null,
        g: null,
        t: null,
        bg: null
    }
};
```

I'm attempting to update one of the `colorValues` properties based on an action.type.

```
return {
    ...state,
    colorValues: {...state.colorValues, action.basePair: action.colorHex}
};
```

`action.basePair` is giving me a parsing error which makes it seem as if I cannot set the property name dynamically using action. If I change `action.basePair` to `g`for example, then the expected behavior occurs and the value of the property `g` is indeed updated as expected.

But is there anyway to do this so that I can set the property name dynamically through action? Thank you.

edit: The code of my action is the following:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    onSetColorValue: (basePair, colorHex) =>
      dispatch({ type: "SET_COLOR_VALUES", basePair: basePair, colorHex: colorHex })
  };
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> action.basePair is giving me a parsing error which makes it seem as if
>   I cannot set the property name dynamically using action.

Wrap `action.basePair` to `[action.basePair]`

```
return {
    ...state,
    colorValues: {...state.colorValues, [action.basePair]: action.colorHex}
};
```

---

Also, it is a good practice to use `payload` key for action params

```
dispatch({ type: "SET_COLOR_VALUES", payload: { basePair, colorHex })
```

Reducer

```
return {
    ...state,
    colorValues: {
      ...state.colorValues, [action.payload.basePair]: action.payload.colorHex
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

when using dynamic value as key, we can use the square brackets notation. Please see below:

```
return {
    ...state,
    colorValues: {
          ...state.colorValues, 
          [action.basePair]: action.colorHex
    }
};
```

You can visit below link for more details:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors

Comment: Thank you for the resource.